# glibc fnmatch vulnerability: how to expose the vulnerability?

Tags: linux, security, glibc

I have to validate a vulnerability on one of our 64-bit systems which is running glibc-2.9 .

http://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.in/2011/02/i-got-accidental-code-execution-via.html

The above link gives a script which when passed a magic number apparently leads to arbitrary code execution. But when I tried it on my system, nothing seems to be happening.
Am I doing something wrong? Does the system crash if the vulnerability exists? How do I detect if it's accidental code execution?

Comment: No. Its a barebones linux 2.6.29.1 box with busybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to run into the problem on a 64-bit machine, you'd have to mimic the original code but provide a number that wraps the stack on a 64-bit machine.  The original number provided was:

1073741796

```
$ bc
z=1073741796
z+28
1073741824
(z+28)*4
4294967296
2^32
4294967296
quit
$
```

So, one way of describing the input number is (ULONG_MAX - 112) / 4.

The analogue number for a 64-bit machine is 4611686018427387876:

```
$ bc
x=2^64
x
18446744073709551616
y=x/4
y
4611686018427387904
y-28
4611686018427387876
quit
$
```

However, to stand a chance of this working, you'd have to modify the reported code to use `strtroull()` or something similar; `atoi()` is normally limited to 32-bit integers and would be no use on the 64-bit numbers above.  The code also contains:

```
num_as = atoi(argv[1]);
if (num_as < 5) {
    errx(1, "Need 5.");
}
p = malloc(num_as);
```

Where `num_as` is a `size_t` and `p` is a `char *`.  So, you'd have to be able to `malloc()` a gargantuan amount of space (almost 4 EiB).  Most people don't have enough virtual memory on their machines, even with disk space for backing, to do that.  Now, maybe, just maybe, Linux would allow you to over-commit (and let the OOM Killer swoop in later), but the `malloc()` would more likely fail.

There were other features that were relevant and affect 32-bit systems in a way that it cannot affect 64-bit systems (yet).

If you're going to stand a chance of reproducing it on a 64-bit machine, you probably have to do a 32-bit compilation.  Then, if the wind is behind you and you have appropriately old versions of the relevant software perhaps you can reproduce it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running on a 64-bit machine then the original circumstances of the bug don't apply. As you can see in Chris' blog, he's using a 32-bit Ubuntu 9.04 system. The exploit relies on causing the stack pointer to wrap about the 32-bit address space, leading to stack corruption.

I gave it a quick try on a 64-bit system with glibc 2.5, but saw malloc() failures instead of crashes.

```
$ ./a.out 3000000000
a.out: malloc() failed.
```

You asked how to identify accidental code execution; with the toy program here, which doesn't carry an exploit / payload, we'd expect to see either a SIGSEGV, SIGILL, or SIGBUS as the CPU tried to "execute" junk parts of the stack, showing up as the respective error message from the shell.

Comment: So does that mean the exploit is not valid on a 64 bit system because malloc limits the number before fnmatch?

Comment: I'm curious if you can get a repro in a [32-bit chroot](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24575) if you're running in [compatibility mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes), as Ubuntu does by default. That would be very useful to have, side-by-side with the current unsuccessful run.

Comment: @Mikhail, it's reasonable to malloc an amount of memory (say, 1.001 GiB) which overflows when multiplied by 4 on a 32 bit architecture. It's unreasonable to malloc 4 exabytes to achieve the same on 64 bit. I think it lives in the category of theoretically, but not practically exploitable today.

Comment: It's reasonable to malloc() 4 exabytes of memory if you've got /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory = 1 (assuming, of course, that you don't actually try to use it)